# Layout vs Schematic in Altium Designer

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I have completed my schematic and PCB design and made a design rule check (DRC). I have realized a concept as LVS - Layout vs Schematic. Can i do it in Altium Designer or does it already done by DRC? If you share ideas i will be happy. Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you asking how to compare the schematic with the PCB to confirm it matches? If that's the case, from the PCB go to Design --> Import Changes From <schematic name> (you should have done this already when you first created your PCB to pull in the components from the schematic)

Comment: No i have seen a concept as layout vs schematic individually and i was curious about that.

Comment: I have never heard of LVS in the scope of PCB design

Answer (score 2):

Design Rules Check (DRC) will check the connections on the PCB against the netlist generated from the schematic, and report any differences (missing or extra connections).  It will also check trace widths, clearances, hole sizes, and other PCB-specific details against the PCB design rules, and report any violations.

You should also run Electrical Rules Check (ERC) on the schematic.  This will report unconnected input pins, multiple outputs driving a signal, and other errors that may occur on the schematic.

Comment: Thank you. I have compiled the schematic project. I think if there is a connection error it can be warned. Is there a conceptional difference between lvs and drc? I guess lvs is commonly used for IC design, but i am not sure.